# Why HTTP_INTERCEPTORS has to be provided for each Lazy Module

Tags: angular, angular7

I have `AuthInterceptor` provided at `AppModule`. Its working fine at `AppModule` however its not working when it comes to `LazyModule`. I had to provide this `interceptor` for all Lazy Module to work.

I am really surprised why is it so. I have implemented the same thing in the other projects which works fine but here I had to provide in the each module. Not sure what is causing the issue.

#### AppModule

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

        //NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ThemeModule.forRoot(),
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
        AuthGuard,
        {
            provide: NbRoleProvider,
            useClass: RoleProvider,
        },
        ZtLoaderService
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

#### AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'pages',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard], // here we tell Angular to check the access with our AuthGuard
        loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
    },
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages'},
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
    useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

#### PagesModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    Dashboard2Module
  ],
  declarations: [
    PagesComponent,
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

#### PagesRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [{
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent2,
    },
    {
        path: 'profile',
        loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule',

    }],
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

#### ProfileModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ThemeModule,
        ProfileRoutingModule,
        Ng2SmartTableModule,

    ],
    declarations: [
        ...routedComponents,
        ...components

    ],
     providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true}],   //<--- Interceptor is provided here. Could be avoided.
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

Comment: Because Angular will create new injector for lazy loaded module

Comment: check this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-dependency-injection-and-tree-shakeable-tokens-4588a8f70d5d

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article, it says `If we have a module with some providers and import this module directly in AppModule or in any other module, which has already been imported in AppModule, then those providers become application-wide providers.` It means it shouldn't be required to provide in each Lazy Module.

Comment: Check this also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6rF16TmB0E

Comment: The search order for lazy loading Module is Module Injector tree

Comment: As per the doc and videos, Lazy Module look for Injector from the Parent Module. In this case, it should get it from the AppModule.

Comment: As far as my understanding it will first look up element injector tree If it does not find it will go for Module injector.

Comment: Can you provide us minimal reproduction on github?